# Scala: Fill the gaps in a List with last non-empty value

Tags: scala, collections

I have a list like:

```
val arr = Array("a", "", "", "b", "c", "")
```

I am looking for a way to create:

```
Array("a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "c")
```

Comment: What have you tried? It's not difficult. And what is the desired output if the first element of the list is ""?

Comment: I tried this: var temp = ""; arr.map{ v => if(v!="") { temp=v;  v } else temp }. Is this the most elegant way?

Comment: @Mohitt I understand that you wan to complete the holes (empty string) with the value of their left neighbor. Isn't it?

Comment: @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo, yes. I tried this : var temp = ""
    arr.map{ case "" => { temp }; case v => {temp=v; v }  }. I am looking for more elegant way.

Comment: What if the first element of the Array is empty? What value should be used?

Comment: @KevinMeredith that should remain as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with fold, the easy (to understand) approach is fold left:

```
(Array.empty[String] /: arr) {
    case (prev, "") => prev :+ prev.lastOption.getOrElse("");
    case (prev, l) => prev :+ l
}

> res01: Array[String] = Array(a, a, a, b, c, c)
```

This builds a new array from the previous by appending `arr` elements or the resulting list's last depending on whether the source element is the empty string or not.

You can also write it as:

```
(Array.empty[String] /: arr) {
    case (Array(), l) => Array(l)
    case (prev, "") => prev :+ prev.last;
    case (prev, l) => prev :+ l
}
```

It can be optimized by using lists and prepend:

```
{(List.empty[String] /: arr) {
    case (Nil, l) => l::Nil
    case (h::tail, "") => h::h::tail;
    case (prev, l) => l::prev
} reverse } toArray
```

In case you don't like the symbolic version of the fold left and fold right methods. Here it comes with its textual identifier:

```
arr.foldLeft(Array.empty[String]) {
    case (prev, "") => prev :+ prev.lastOption.getOrElse("");
    case (prev, l) => prev :+ l
}

arr.foldLeft(List.empty[String]) {
    case (Nil, l) => l::Nil
    case (h::tail, "") => h::h::tail;
    case (prev, l) => l::prev
}.reverse toArray
```

Its exactly the same approach and implementation but with a different name.

Comment: Using `/:` is certainly not idiomatic Scala. `Another example, where I have doubts if not regrets are the /: and :\ operators in scala.collections. They are cute synonyms for folds, and I am still fond of the analogy with falling dominoes they evoke. But in retrospect I think maybe they did give a bad example for others to go overboard with symbolic operators.` - [Odersky](http://www.scala-lang.org/blog/2016/01/02/new-year-resolutions.html)

Comment: @KevinMeredith Its "a bad example" not bad itself but I'll edit my answer to include a textual version. I wouldn't go so far as to say it is not idiomatic.

Comment: hey Pablo - thanks. Also, I should've said `not idiomatic [in my opinion]`, pointing to that post by Odersky to support my argument.

Comment: @KevinMeredith He likes it but regrets that it became an example hinting that symbolic operators are preferred which, in some cases, drove to an abusive use of symbolic identifiers ;P No problem however, it is just that I've and acquired taste for `:\` and  `:/`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is an elegant way, but figured out one solution:

```
var temp = "" 
arr.map{ case "" => { temp }; case v => {temp=v; v } }
```

Comment: It solves the problem right away so its a good solution, however it is an imperative solution, that is, not pure in the sense that it presents side effects. Depending on your program context than can become a source of bugs. E.g: What if someone, in a future commit, inserts code between the first and second line which changes `temp`?

Answer (score 0):

I think Mohitt's answer is a clear solution ... but  Pablo Francisco Pérez Hidalgo is right that there are side effects

Maybe we could include the variable inside of a function to avoid changing the temp variable by some other developers

```
(x: Array[String]) => { var last = ""; x.map { v => if (v != "") last = v; last } }
```

to be used like this:

```
val fillEmpty = (x: Array[String]) => { var last = ""; x.map { v => if (v != "") last = v; last } }
fillEmpty(arr)
```